# Insert Subsystem in existin line - using m-script

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am searching for a code snippet  to insert subsystem in to a line connecting two blocks in simulink using m-script !! . Attached snap for the manual operations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and **post what you've tried** with a clear explanation of what **isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I suggest reading [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is command line functionality to insert a block into an existing line.

You'll need to

1. find the handle to the line, using `find_system`
2. delete the line, using `delete_line`
3. insert the new block, using `add_block`
4. connect a line to the new block inport, using `add_line`
5. connect a line to the new block outport, using `add_line`

Comment: Thanks for the Input